# Consulta a base de datos con mysqli en php5

Tags: mysqli, php5

Estoy intentando que al hacer una consulta a una base de datos, si el campo de imagen no posee una me muestre una foto genérica, pero si esta la imagen me muestre la correcta.

```
<?php
$query="
SELECT
images.image
FROM
images
WHERE
images.object_id = $dni_i
";
$aRes = $conn->query($query);
foreach($aRes AS $row) {
$avatar = $row["image"];
}
?>
<?php if (is_null($avatar)) { ?>
<div><img src="imgp/assets/img/default_avatar.png" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail mb-1" 
alt=""/></div>
<?php } else { ?>
<div><img src="imgp/assets/img/<?= $avatar ?>" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail mb-1" 
alt=""/></div>
<?php } ?>
```

El error que me dá es que no entiende la variable $avatar

Comment: Comenta o borra ese `foreach` y prueba con `$avatar = $aRes->fetch()->image;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias cosas en tu código:

1. En `mysqli`, para encontrar los resultados de la consulta debes usar uno de los métodos `fetch` (para consultas preparadas [`fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) y para las otras consultas cualquiera de los métodos `fetch_` indicados [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)).
2. Si esperas una sola fila, pon un `LIMIT 1` a la consulta. Y en ese caso no necesitas leer los datos en un bucle, basta con aplicar el método `fetch` que vayas a usar directamente.
3. Tu consulta es vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*. Deberías usar [consultas preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php).
4. Evita mezclas de bloques PHP / HTML. Produce un código ilegible.
5. Verifica cada cosa, para no escribir un código ingenuo que se quedará mudo ante cualquier problema. Establecer control de errores es fundamental en la programación.

Aplicando todo lo dicho, tu código podría quedar así:

```
<?php

    $query="SELECT
            images.image
        FROM images
        WHERE
            images.object_id = ? LIMIT 1";
    # Valor por defecto
    $avatar="imgp/assets/img/default_avatar.png";
    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $dni_i);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            $stmt->bind_result($avatar);
            $stmt->fetch();
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
    $conn->close();    
    printf('<div><img src="%s" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail mb-1" 
    alt=""/></div>',$avatar);
?>
```